# SQL XQuery add id attribute where there isn't one

Tags: sql, xquery, identifier

I've got an xml collection:

```xml
<Cars>
    <Car id="1ECFD1AB-758D-4BA1-8D4A-387861E0B2E3">etc.</Car>
    <Car id="5C71E7A8-46C7-41F8-860E-69C95F917AD2">etc.</Car>
    <Car>etc.</Car>
    <Car>etc.</Car>
</Cars>
```

I'm passing this into an xml variable in a stored proc and need a way to add an id attribute with a new guid for cars without one.

What is the best/quickest/most efficient way to do this using XQuery

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with usage with SQL, but this might work if you can get a variable inserted where it says `GUID-GOES-HERE` (and replacing the doc() syntax as appropriate for your environment):

```
<Cars> {
for $Car in doc('test')//Car
return <Car id='{ if ($Car/@id) then $Car/@id else "GUID-GOES-HERE"}'>{$Car/text()}</Car>
} </Cars>
```

(Tested on http://basex.org/products/live-demo/ )

Note that this is using XQuery, rather than XQUF (which I also don't know the level of support with SQL).